# Running console app as a part of integration test c#

Tags: c#, nunit

I need to create a integration test that will call a console application. Is there a way to run the console apps inside integration test?

Answer (score 2):

There are probably many ways to tackle this issue, however, given the little details, there are two ways which I can come up with

#### Starting the app in another process

```
var consoleApp = Process.Start("path/to/your/app.exe");
consoleApp.WaitForExit();
```

#### Executing the Main Method of the App

This would be the best way to do it, provided the UnitTestProject has a reference to your ConsoleApp (Project or assembly-reference)

```
Program.Main();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you console Application returns some value, you could analyse it in your test, something like:

```
Process P = Process.Start(path, param);
P.WaitForExit();
int result = P.ExitCode;
Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
```

`path` is path to your console application exe and `param` are parameters you want to provide..